# jQuery swfobject params as variable

Tags: jquery, swfobject

I've got problem with jQuery swfobject. How to add "params1" variable under height: 385?

```
            var params1 = {
                play: false,
                menu: false
            };

            flashMovie = $('#Flash .movie');
            flashMovie.flash({
                swf: 'swf/some_flash.swf',
                width: 640,
                height: 385
            });
```

Greetings!

Comment: swfobject is not a jQuery object, and add what code where, what?

Comment: Thank You for point that out. My mistake. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to merge two objects together (or [jQuery.merge()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) ) i'm not really sure which one works for you, and i have never used them, but hopefully you can read the documentation and figure it out.

**EDIT 2:**

Example:

```
        var params1 = {
            play: false,
            menu: false
        };
        var baseparams = {
            swf: 'swf/some_flash.swf',
            width: 640,
            height: 385
        }
        $.extend(baseparams , params1);

        flashMovie = $('#Flash .movie');
        flashMovie.flash(baseparams);
```

this wasn't tested. it's a rough sketch.

Comment: Very interesting approach. I will try test it. Thank You!

Comment: Don't know why I had a brainfart and didn't use $.extend... so much easier :)